# Highcharts x-axis datetime - different format of first and last (boundaries) labels

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, axis, axis-labels

How to set first and last datatime labels on x-axis in different format? I need this labels:

full datetime | time | time ... time | time | full datetime

Now I have the time everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the highcharts formatter for labels you can achieve what you seek. The formatter has two values `this.isFirst` and `this.isLast` which helps you distinguish start and end values.

I made a simple example using this formatter:

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      if (this.isFirst || this.isLast) {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %e %b - %H %M %S', this.value);
      } else {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H %M %S', this.value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Working example**: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/n8o32ejx/

**DOCS on dateformat**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

**API on highcharts formatter**: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter